# Create file to Onedrive programmatically from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onedrive

I want to create a doc, docx, pptx or excel file from C# direct to my Onedrive account.
I have try this but it's not working for me. Anybody have any idea what I did wrong ? Thanks

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateWordFile()
{
   LiveLoginResult loginStatus = await authClient.InitializeWebSessionAsync(HttpContext);
   if (loginStatus.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
   {
        var fileData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        fileData.Add("name", "Document.docx");
        fileData.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x");
        fileData.Add("type", "file");

        LiveOperationResult getResult = await connectedClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive/files", fileData);
    }

    return View();
}
```

EDITED:
The error that I get is this one:

*"The header 'Content-Type' is missing the required parameter: 'boundary'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException: The header 'Content-Type' is missing the required parameter: 'boundary'."*

Comment: Error messages, what exactly does not work?

Comment: Make sure you're updated to use the Live SDK 5.6 binary.

Comment: I put in the post the error message that I get and also already had the 5.6 update (it's not because of the version of Live SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I create a docx file from c#. I put here the solution (the code from the method is not refactored so it can be split in a severeal methods).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateWordFile()
{
    LiveLoginResult loginStatus = await authClient.InitializeWebSessionAsync(HttpContext);
    if (loginStatus.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        connectedClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.authClient.Session);
        string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=" + this.authClient.Session.AccessToken;

         MemoryStream streamDoc = new MemoryStream();
        DocX doc = DocX.Create(streamDoc);

        string headlineText = "Constitution of the United States";
        string paraOne = ""
            + "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, "
            + "establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, "
            + "promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves "
            + "and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United "
            + "States of America.";

        // A formatting object for our headline:
        var headLineFormat = new Formatting();
        headLineFormat.FontFamily = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Arial Black");
        headLineFormat.Size = 18D;
        headLineFormat.Position = 12;

        // A formatting object for our normal paragraph text:
        var paraFormat = new Formatting();
        paraFormat.FontFamily = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Calibri");
        paraFormat.Size = 10D;

        doc.InsertParagraph(headlineText, false, headLineFormat);
        doc.InsertParagraph(paraOne, false, paraFormat);

        doc.Save();

        var docFile = File(streamDoc, "application/octet-stream", "FileName.docx");
        MemoryStream streamFile = new MemoryStream();
        docFile.FileStream.Position = 0;
        docFile.FileStream.CopyTo(streamFile);

        var bites = streamFile.ToArray();
        Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream(bites);

        try
        {
            LiveOperationResult getResult = await connectedClient.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", docFile.FileDownloadName, stream2, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {

        }
    }

    return View("~/Views/Auth/EditFile.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: how do i get Microsoft.Live dll?

Comment: Through nuget package manager console. Check there and you will find the OneDrive SDK

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. The dictionary provided to PostAsync only populates fields in the request body, and so adding Content-Type in there doesn't have any effect
2. File resources are mean to be created using the UploadAsync method, which requires content. I don't believe there's an API you can call to tell the service to create a blank Office document.

Comment: I succeded to upload word, excel and many other documents in onedrive using UploadAsync(). Here is an example of how I called the method: " LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await connectedClient.UploadAsync(folderId, fileName, fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);" where folderId = "me/skydrive", fileName = "Document.docx", filestream = the inputStream of the file that I picked from my computer and it created the doc file in onedrive. I thhink that in the "fileStream" is set the contentType automatically, so I think that should be a way to set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have something else. I created an HttpWebRequest and I set some parameters. Now it create the file to my onedrive account as a docx but when I try to open the file from my account an error message appear and it's saying something like "Something wrong has happened. We could not open the file". The file exist but it can't be open.

The code that I wrote is this. Any suggestions ?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateWordFile()
{
    string body = "--A300x\r\n"
            + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"csm.docx\"\r\n"
            + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "This is some content\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "--A300x--\r\n";

    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

    LiveLoginResult loginStatus = await authClient.InitializeWebSessionAsync(HttpContext);
    if (loginStatus.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        connectedClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.authClient.Session);
        string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=" + this.authClient.Session.AccessToken;


        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x";
        httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest2.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
        Stream stream2 = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();
        stream2.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
        }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also foud the answer to create an xlsx file.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateExcelFile()
        {
            LiveLoginResult loginStatus = await authClient.InitializeWebSessionAsync(HttpContext);
            if (loginStatus.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                connectedClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.authClient.Session);
                string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=" + this.authClient.Session.AccessToken;

                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

                // create sheet
                XSSFSheet sh = (XSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
                // 10 rows, 10 columns
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var r = sh.CreateRow(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    {
                        r.CreateCell(j);
                    }
                }

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                wb.Write(stream);
                stream.Dispose();

                var arrBites = stream.ToArray();

                MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream(arrBites);

                var docFile = File(newStream, "application/octet-stream", "Excel.xlsx");
                MemoryStream streamFile = new MemoryStream();
                docFile.FileStream.Position = 0;
                docFile.FileStream.CopyTo(streamFile);

                var bites = streamFile.ToArray();
                Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream(bites);

                try
                {
                    LiveOperationResult getResult = await connectedClient.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", docFile.FileDownloadName, stream2, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```