# Virtual streamed files like sync clients

Tags: winapi, filesystems

I have seen many sync clients such as Dropbox that can create "virtual" files that do not really exist on disk. They have a size and you can open them in any program, but they are streamed e.g. from the Dropbox servers.

I don't know how this is called, and I can't find any information about this on the internet. Do I have to write a file system driver for that, or is it possible to do this for example with the Windows API?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is a file hosting service. (From [WiKi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(service)))

On Windows you can use [OneDrive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/docs) to [store files on Cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview#store-your-apps-files-in-a-powerful-cloud).

Please refer to "[Create file to Onedrive programmatically from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564661/create-file-to-onedrive-programmatically-from-c)" for an sample.

Similar topic: "[How to create a virtual file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080892/how-to-create-a-virtual-file)"